# Remove any culture date time c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture

i want to remove any culture from date time and of curse load date from string there is big problem for my project on each computer

this is my current save date time code:

```
#region Date Of Birth
DateTime? dateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.dateOfBirth))
{
    dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", (model.dateOfBirth)));
Languages.Properties.Resources.error_date_format);
}

 #endregion
```

This code work on server but in my computer is `fa-IR` and time will be `6:30:20 ب.ض` not pm

My website is mutilanual and I change thread culture is each post to load errors and message correctly.

An other problem is when I want to parse date from string server work well but in my computer

```
 DateTime dateStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dataRowcontentResult[i]); //string is 2017/12/31 12:59:00
```

`An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`

`{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}`

this is my string `2017/12/31 12:59:00`

This code work on server without any problem

> The question is how avoid this problem and what is best way to store data in database for multilingual and multi-culture websites.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings, store them as DateTime, and when you parse the strings from user input if you already have the correct culture on the thread just use DateTime.Parse(thestring), do not specify invariant culture

Comment: @Gusman  I store data many places as date time but I need this time convert string to date time. I must convert culture to my culture when I culture is `fa-IR` data format is not correct in date time table

Comment: **DateTime.ParseExact** if you have common format for all records

Comment: @AntonMaiorov Thank you. This helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(dataRowcontentResult[i], "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", provider);
```